# series it represents Pi

Tags: calculus

The series $$\pi =4 \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{2} (-1)^n \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)^{-2 n}}{1-4 n^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ converge fast to Pi , it seems that artan(x) is involved where it come from ??

Comment: Use partial fraction decomposition. Then you will get two Taylor series for arctangent.

Comment: 3 Pi ???.. are you sure

Comment: This series doesn't converge to $\pi$.

Comment: I think i found a solution using tylor series and partialfraction decomposition I found $$4 \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sqrt{2} (-1)^{3 n} x^{-2 n}}{1-4 n^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=4 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{x^2 \left(-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)+x-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)$$ when $$4 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{x^2 \left(-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)+x-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sqrt{2} x}\right)\text{/.}\, x\to \sqrt{2}+1=\pi$$